# How to pass multiple arguments in command line using python

Tags: python

(My Code):

```
import csv
import re
import string
import sys
import fileinput
import os
import random
import glob
import getopt

def getSymbols(filename):
    f = file(filename)
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break
        print line, 
    f.close()
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 'No action specified.'
    sys.exit()

    elif:
        print "No option"
    sys.exit()

    else:
        for filename in sys.argv[1]:
            readfile(filename)

    with open(filename) as f:
         for line in f:
             if 'symbols' in line:
                print "Total Number of Symbols:\n",line.strip(' has ');
getSymbols(filename)
```

I have a requirement and I am not able to find a solution:

How can I pass multiple file path as arguments in the command line ?
Eg:

```
test.py C:\test1.txt C:\test2.txt
```

I have used the code as mentioned above to pass the file path as an argument and `filename` is the reference to that argument that I pass and it should print the total number of symbols. Please send me the sample code related to this issue.

Comment: Voting to close as *not a real question* due to *send me teh codez*. This is not welcome here.

Answer (score 11):

The files are at `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, and so on.  So just take a slice.

```
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    readfile(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use
    len(sys.argv)
to count number of arguments and use them as sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2] etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that the [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module is what you want for your program.